# Outer product - what about it's (co/contra)variance?

Tags: linear-algebra

In wikipedia [HERE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outer_product) is article about outer product - in that aricle author use covariant vectors (vectors with bottom indexes) (for simplicity I use 3D case)

$$
u=\begin{bmatrix}
    u_1 &
    u_2 &
    u_3
\end{bmatrix} = [u_i],
\qquad
v=\begin{bmatrix}
    v_1 &
    v_2 &
    v_3
\end{bmatrix} = [v_i]
$$

$$ u\otimes v \equiv 
\begin{bmatrix}
    u_1v_1 & u_1v_2 & u_1v_3 \\
    u_2v_1 & u_2v_2 & u_2v_3 \\
    u_3v_1 & u_3v_2 & u_3v_3
  \end{bmatrix} = [T_{ij}], \qquad T_{ij}=u_iv_j $$

so here from two covariant vectors we get covariant tensor. But further author write outer product as matrix multiplication (I change his formula because he probably is not aware that bottom indexes means row vectors)

$$ u\otimes v = u^T\cdot v $$

**Problem:** with this notation is that when we made transposition $u^T$ we change vector variance (from covariant to contravariant) then result tensor should also change covariance

$$
u\cdot v^T =[u_i]^T\cdot[v_i] = [u^i]\cdot[v_i] = 
\begin{bmatrix}
    u^1 \\
    u^2 \\
    u^3
\end{bmatrix}
\cdot
\begin{bmatrix}
    v_1 &
    v_2 &
    v_3
\end{bmatrix}
=
[T^i_j] \neq [T_{ij}]
$$

May be this formula (in form $u\otimes v=u\cdot v^T$) is valid only for orthogonal coordinate systems (where covariant vectors are equal to contravariant vectors) ?

**Question**: Does outer product operation can be used for row and column vectors - and does below equations are correct (in terms of tensor/vector variance) ?
$$ [u^i]\otimes[v^j]=[T^{ij}] \\
 [u_i]\otimes[v^j]=[T_i^j] \\
 [u^i]\otimes[v_j]=[T^i_j] \\
 [u_i]\otimes[v_j]=[T_{ij}] \\
$$

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if any of this answers your question(s), but the comment I was trying to write got longer and longer. I hope something of this is helpful:

First of all, there are different conventions in different areas of mathematics, not all of them use the idea of "vector variance" ("bottom index means row vector" etc.) which to my knowledge is mostly used in areas related to physics. In other areas, the position of an index or the distinction between row and column vectors is not relevant.

For me, it seems the main problem you are having with the article is due to these differences in conventions.

In the article you linked to, first, we are given
$$ u = (u_1,\dots,u_m) $$
and 
$$ v = (v_1,\dots,v_n)$$
(row vectors by the looks of it) but when relating the outer product to matrix multiplication, it is said that $u$ and $v$ should be considered as $m \times 1$- and $n \times 1$-column vectors, respectively, in order for 
$$\begin{equation} u \otimes v = u v^T \end{equation}$$
to make sense.

The outer product is essentially defined as a map 
$$\otimes : \mathbb{R}^m \times \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^{m \times n} $$
with position $(i,j)$ of $u \otimes v$ being the product of the $i$th entry of $u$ with the $j$th entry of $v$. The position of the indexes (top/bottom) is not relevant to define this map and can be chosen arbitrarily (at least from the viewpoint of someone not adhering to the vector variance convention).

Concerning the question of orthogonal coordinate systems, 
the article explains the distinction between the outer and the inner product and thereby mentions the identity $$ \langle u,v \rangle = u^T v $$
(for $m = n$ and column vectors $u$ and $v$)
so the matrix and vectors representations are with respect to an orthonormal coordinate system.

In fact, I would say the article is written as to consider the vector space $\mathbb{R}^n$ with its usual inner product and does not consider an abstract inner vector space where the choice of basis is not that straightforward.

That being said, the distinction between bottom and top indexes has advantages when we consider the usage of matrices. In this context, 
we consider the column space $\mathbb{R}^{n \times 1}$ and identify its dual space (the space of linear maps $\mathbb{R}^{n \times 1} \to \mathbb{R}$) with the row space $\mathbb{R}^{1 \times n}$.

The space of $m \times n$-matrices can now be used in various ways which leads to the different ways of writing indexes on top and on the bottom.

A $m \times n$-matrix $[A^i_j]$ is used to represent a linear map $\mathbb{R}^{n \times 1} \to \mathbb{R}^{m \times 1}, [v^j] \mapsto [\sum_j A^i_j v^j]$ whereas a $m \times n$-matrix $[A_{i,j}]$ is used to represent a bilinear map $\mathbb{R}^{m \times 1} \times \mathbb{R}^{n \times 1} \to \mathbb{R}, ([u^i],[v^j]) \mapsto \sum_{i,j} u^i A_{i,j} v^j$. We can thus interpret the space of $m \times n$-matrices in different ways.

For now, let us consider $\mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$ as space of linear maps, so that composition of linear maps corresponds to matrix multiplication
$$\mathbb{R}^{l \times m} \times \mathbb{R}^{m \times n} \to \mathbb{R}^{l \times n}, ([A^i_{j}],[B^{j}_{k}]) \mapsto [\sum_{j} A^i_j B^j_k].$$

The problem is now that the article does not have this viewpoint. Of course we can define any sorts of maps 
$$ ([u^i],[v^j]) \mapsto [u^i v^j]$$
$$ ([u^i],[v^j]) \mapsto [u^i v_j]$$
$$ ([u^i],[v^j]) \mapsto [u_i v^j]$$
$$ ([u^i],[v^j]) \mapsto [u_i v_j]$$
but what of this makes sense?

If we want to have $u \otimes v = u v^T$ for column vectors $u$ and $v$, then we have 
$$ [u^i] \otimes [v^j] = [u^i][v^j]^T  = [u^i][v_j] = [u^i v_j]$$
as you already calculated which gives a matrix representing a linear map. In fact, this is the map $w \mapsto \langle v,w \rangle u$.

For other combinations of column and row vectors we clearly do not have $u \otimes v = u v^T$ because the right hand side just does not make any sense in general or would yield a scalar instead of a matrix.

Still, you could argue that the definition of outer product (position $(i,j)$ is $i$th component times $j$th component) makes sense regardless of whether the input vectors are rows or columns and this is true. However, if you try to express this in terms of matrix multiplication and transposition, if needed, and use these to calculate the tensor variance of the corresponding matrix, you will find that all combinations of column and row vector yield a matrix $[T^i_j]$.

Comment: Thank you for your effort. For me the distinction between covariant and contravariant vector is important - because I have some work using non-orthogonal curvilinear coordinates. **So I need outer-product definition which properly deal with input vectors variance.** I found something interesting info about tensor representation and variance using matrixes [HERE](https://www.vttoth.com/CMS/physics-notes/139-on-tensors-and-their-matrix-representations) - I think there is the key to solve all my problems ;) - but still not sure. What do you think?

Comment: The outer-product is usually used with tensors which are designed to work in curvilinear coordinates so I hope definition which deal with vector variance exists. Another interesting article about tensor representation and variance using matrixes (similar to first one) [HERE](https://vixra.org/pdf/1710.0196v1.pdf).

Comment: I do not know much about the use of outer products, another way to go about it, would be to consider the abstract tensor product of vector spaces. This should get you compatibility with variance as you can distinguish between $V \otimes V$ and $V \otimes V^*$ for example.